# "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" on File "goslate.py", line 222 while installing goslate using pip

Tags: python, pip

I fail to install goslate with `sudo pip install goslate`. Log of error message is below. What I am missing? Or what is my computer (Debian) missing?

It is possible to install the package in Python 2, but not in Python 3. `python3 --version:`
`Python 3.2.3`
`type python3:`
`python3 is hashed (/usr/bin/python3)`

```
    Downloading/unpacking goslate
  Running setup.py egg_info for package goslate
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      File "/home/admin/build/goslate/setup.py", line 8, in <module>
        import goslate as module
      File "goslate.py", line 222
        return tuple(u'' for i in range(len(self._writing))) , unicode(target_language)
                       ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
  File "/home/admin/build/goslate/setup.py", line 8, in <module>
    import goslate as module
  File "goslate.py", line 222
    return tuple(u'' for i in range(len(self._writing))) , unicode(target_language)
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/admin/build/goslate
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 104, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 245, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1009, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 225, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 256, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/admin/build/goslate
```

Comment: Is there a need to install it using sudo? I created a new virtualenv and installed it using pip/3, nothing abnormal.

Comment: No, but I also tried without sudo, and the result is the same.

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of `python3 --version` and `type python3`

Comment: @Braiam: question updated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade to python 3.4.

Comment: Indeed, it can be installed in Python 2 without any problem. However, in theory it should support  Python 3 too according to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/goslate

Comment: try to update python 3 to version 3.4.3

Comment: Python 3.4.3 worked. Using Python 2 is not a solution, it's avoiding the problem.